# How to Reduce The Nested Sum $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{i<j} \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: computer-science, summation

I'm trying to find the expected number of swaps in a algorithm I'm working on. I've gotten to this point:

$E[S] =\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{i<j} \frac{1}{2}$

I don't know how to reduce this further. The answer is supposed to be n(n-1)/4, but I don't know how to get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have actually simplifies to $\frac14n(n+1)$:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\frac12&=\frac12\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}1\\
&=\frac12\sum_{j=1}^nj&&\text{since there are }j\text{ terms}\\
&=\frac12\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2&&\text{by the well-known formula}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}4\;.
\end{align*}$$

If the inner sum started at $i=1$, you’d have $$\frac12\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k=\frac12\cdot\frac{(n-1)n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}4\;.$$

Comment: @Ryan Hurley:  If you're wondering where you can find these properties, check out the wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities

Comment: Thank you so much...this is perfect!

Comment: @Ryan: You’re very welcome!